# Api Google - SEO - Google Index e Google plus via json

Tags: c#, json, api, google, seo

Preciso recuperar via json ou alguma outra forma as informações de SEO do Google para alimentar minha base de dados..

Por enquanto são apenas o Google Index e o Google+

Alguem conhece como posso fazer isso??
Ou alguem tem algum exemplo de utilização da API do Google pra pegar essas informações?

Answer (score 0):

Alguém me ajuda por favor.

Preciso recuperar via codígo o Google Index do meu site.
Quanto coloco essa informação no google "site:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br" eu obtenho

> "Aproximadamente 13.400 resultados (0,28 segundos) "

Quero saber se via API consigo recuperar essa informação, se tem outro jeito.